# Will moving from QA to Dev back to QA make it harder to find another Dev position?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, career-switch, software-development

The current job I work at is pretty dead end (Dev) but it's full time with benefits and I'm salaried. I don't particularly like it anymore so I've been looking around.

I found a position in an industry I've wanted to get back into for awhile. The position (QA) is contract though with potential to hire FT (maybe), making 20 percent less than what I'm making now, hourly, with no benefits, working only 30 hours a week. Seems terrible right?

I have an interview coming up so regardless I'll go to check it out. Again I want to be in this industry but not necessarily doing this particular job (QA) but I'm hoping that by proving myself I'd be able to wiggle into a position (Dev) that I really want within the same industry. I've done QA before and I'm actually quite good at it so I have no worries about being competent enough.

I'd continue to look for other jobs during this time as well because I know I couldn't rely on being hired FT after the contract ends.

What would you do in my situation? Would moving back into a QA role after having been in a Dev role make me undesirable for future Dev positions? I didn't go to college for CS so the fact I was able to get a Dev position in the first place with just a bit of self-study is miraculous. I don't want to screw myself over and throw even more hoops in front of myself than the ones I already have to jump through.

Comment: Your job role matters more than the industry you work in.

Comment: questioner is not asking "what to do" but asking for the potential impact of decisions being being made, which we are qualified to answer based on our own experiences. I don't see how it's off-topic and why it's getting close votes.

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes

People who hire developers want people with a consistent history of development, even if it's support. Development is development, but QA is **not development**.

In my opinion, taking a job in QA is worse than not working at all.  It's worse than a gap.  You're telling any future employer that you can't make up your mind over QA or development. Depending on the mindset of the person doing the hiring, they may well just assume that you can't handle development since many developers (incorrectly) assume that development is harder than QA.

You've going to spend a lot of time thinking about what you're going to tell future interviewers when you apply for a dev job and they ask, "why did you leave a perfectly good development job to go into QA?"

I'd rather hire someone with a gap than someone who can't decide what they're looking for in a career.  It's ok to switch careers but to switch and then switch back creates more problems.

Comment: Wow ... I'm coming at this from the opposite direction.  I see a developer who's had roles in QA or Operations as a pearl beyond price, because he has a good idea of how a program affects the downstream groups.  If I could **make** all devs take a 6-month tour of one or both of these groups, I'd do it!